# Issue setting up freeradius, Google LDAP and Unifi Controllers

Tags: ldap, g-suite, freeradius

I'm trying to use freeradius as a radius server that uses Google's LDAP for a directory, for Unifi USG4's VPN.

When I don't use CHAP / MSCHAPv2, it works fine!

However, MSCHAPv2 is required.

When using MSCHAPv2, I get this from freeradius:

```
Auth: (4) Login incorrect (mschap: FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication): [myusername/<via Auth-Type = mschap>]
```

I see that it's telling me "exactly" what is wrong. What has "No NT/LM-Password"? My radius client or Google LDAP? Any idea on how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the Unifi USG, why not use the Radius server that's built into the device?

Comment: I don't think the USG radius server can bind to ldap?